# Save password for Windows Samba server for printing in Gnome?

Tags: gnome, smb

Unfortunately for us Linux users, our University printer works over the Samba protocoll.

After configuring it in CUPS I can print, but I have to enter username and password everytime with no option to save. I also used the `username:password@adress` syntax, but to no avail. The gnome key manager also does not seem to be used there.

Is there any way to save the credentials?

I use Arch Linux 3.15.3-1-ARCH with GNOME Shell 3.12.2.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the full URL for accessing a SMB printer?

Log in on the CUPS web interface and choose to add a new printer. As a device choose "Windows Printer via SAMBA".

For the device location, enter:

```
smb://username:password@hostname/printer_name
```

The above is from the Arch Linux [CUPS Printer Sharing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CUPS_printer_sharing) wiki page.

**Note:** to log in othe CUPS web interface, use `http://localhost:631`

Answer (score 0):

In 2024 you can to this using `gvfs-mount` from the command line or Nautilus from the GUI.

See [this blog post](https://www.techytalk.info/mount-remote-share-at-login-ubuntu-linux-using-gvfs-mount/) about it.

Comment: This answer could benefit from elaboration. How is **gvfs-mount** used exactly? What are the key points to using Nautilus GUI for the issue? Please don't post external links without at least a short summary, because the external URLs could be changed or removed by their authors, leaving the answer incomplete for future readers.